# Object-languages misdescribed by UML?

Tags: class, inheritance, casting, uml, programming-languages

I've read that UML assumes by default that :

1. a class can inherit several others
2. an object is an instance of only one class
3. an object of a given class cannot change to another class

This leads me to the question : as there are 3 hypothesis, there are 2^3 possible combinations. Could you give me languages which would be examples of each of them ?

I mean for me Java is "false-true-true" and C++ is "true-true-true". What about the 6 others ? Or did I misinterpret the assumptions ?

Comment: Where did you read that and why do you think those are hypotheses?

Comment: It's written as it in a presentation taught in a college here in France.

Comment: You won't get examples here (it's off-topic). UML is a language itself. Programming languages can do what they want and are not bound to what UML says at all.

Comment: 2 and 3 are untrue in UML.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I agree with you : languages can do what they want and are not due to conform to the UML standard. That's precisely why I'm asking for examples which do not. I'm not sure to understand why it is off-topic, we can speak of languages on stackoverflow, no ?

Comment: @JimL. Wow, thanks. Could you explain ? I was pretty sure this course was correct.

Comment: The metamodel allows an InstanceSpecification to have many types. There is no restriction I've ever seen about changing those types over time. UML has no true instances, so why would it say anything about them?

Comment: @JimL. I'm sorry, this example is too specific for me. Do you know any "implementation-oriented" language which would work this way ? I would really be curious to try. Or is it only a conceptual specification ?

Comment: UML is a conceptual specification language. How to map UML to a particular language is another matter. Some languages that allow instances to have many changing types are RDFS and OWL, also called the Semantic Web.

Comment: I recommend to go through this list of programming languages and see which fits: http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/abc.html Have fun!

Comment: @JimL. Well done, that's a brilliant answer. In my convention, rdfs is "false-false-false".

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the UML 2.5 standard of the OMG, to have a definitive answer:

**1.Class inheritance**

The UML 2.5 standard clearly defines that a class can have none or several superclasses and, that conversely, a class can be superclass of none or several classes (see section 11.4.2 and 11.8.3.6).

So UML definitively allows multiple inheritance (as in  C++ or Python).  But you may as well restrict yourself and use only single inheritance and several interface implementations, like in Java and C#.  You'd use a realization relationship to show the "inheritance" from an abstract interface (the inheritance arrow is then dotted).

**2. Objects and classes**

> **9.8.1:** InstanceSpecifications represent instances of Classifiers in a modeled
>   system. They are often used to model example configurations of
>   instances.

FYI: the terms used in the standard are a little more general, but an object is an instance, and a class a classifier.  This definition is then further refined in the semantcs in chapter 9.8.3 :

> The InstanceSpecification may represent:
>  • Classification of the
>   instance by **one or more Classifiers**, any of which may be abstract.

So UML allows objects to be an instantiation of several classes.  I don't know languages that allow this, but if you do don't hesitate to comment ;-).

**3. Changing class of object**

I must admit that I can't answer this answer 100%.  I don't think so, because, becoming an instance of another class would mean to re-insantiate a class, so it's not corresponding anymore to the definition of an instantiation.
Furthermore (see 9.8.3):

> An InstanceSpecification may represent an instance at a point in time
>   (a snapshot). Changes to the instance may be modeled using multiple
>   InstanceSpecification, one for each snapshot.

This is somewhat ambiguous: a given object in a given diagram can't change classes.  However, you can represent several times the object in different diagrams (snapshot) to show a change.

**Conclusions**

So your assumption 1 is true, 2 is false, and 3 true or false depending if you're reasoning at diagram or model level.

Comment: Thank you Christophe, this is a very interesting answer, which prove the original question was not correct. I'm going to upvote, but not mark the answer as accepted, as I was looking for languages. Jim's suggestion, rdfs, is a good start. As far as I understand, you suggest there might not exist so many languages for which (2) and (3) are possible.